# Change position field from numeric to alphanumeric. Where to find $category->setPostedProducts?

Tags: magento-1.9

Each Product has a different position in each category. The position only accept numeric and will change it to alphanumeric. So I set the position from catalog_category_product and _index in the database to "varchar".

But it still wont work. So I think, that there is another validation in the php Code.
I found the Code in:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/CategoryController.php:
Line 320:

    $category->setPostedProducts($products);
```

But i cant find the declaration of the Method "setPostedProducts" anywhere. I searched all files.
And where is the MySQL "Update product..." Statement, so that I can check the value before it will be send to the DB?
Can someone tell me where can find it? Or I can solve this problem?

The Second thing is, how can i display the Position to the Frontend (.phtml)
I Want to show it in Product Listing and View.
Thanks

Greetings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I got it.

```
In Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category.php Line 342 and 357
Change (int) to (string)
```

And

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tab/Product.php
Delete Line 137:
```

To show it in frontend:

```
$_product->getcat_index_position();
```

Comment: Please accept your own answer if your problem is resolved. This website is still in beta and we need a global answer rate of 80% http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers